# How can I import a module into main() from a sub function?

Tags: python, import

In a Python script, I would like to control the importing of a module into the main() from a sub function. Is this possible? How?

Why: I have a sub function that handles command line arguments (using argparse) and would like to import a module based on user input. Specifically, I would like to let the user specify the backend for matplotlib, which has to be set before importing matplotlib.pylab. However, I think the question has more general use.

Here is a code snippet:

```
def main():

    args = handleCommandLine();

    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)   # ERROR: plt not defined

    # Snip ...


def handleCommandLine():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    p.add_argument('--backend', '-b', default=None, help='Specify plotting backend')
    args = p.parse_args()

    if args.backend != None:
        matplotlib.use(args.backend)  #Must occur before importing pyplot

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   #Must occur after setting backend, if desired
    return args
```

Comment: Why can't you just import it into the whole file?

Comment: @Daenyth: Matplotlib requires the backend to be set before importing the plotting functions from matplotlib.pyplot so it has to occur in the code

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you'd like it to behave as though you executed `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` at the top of the module, even though you didn't, use a global:

```
def handleCommandLine():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    p.add_argument('--backend', '-b', default=None, help='Specify plotting backend')
    args = p.parse_args()

    if args.backend != None:
        matplotlib.use(args.backend)  #Must occur before importing pyplot

    global plt  #Style choice: Can also be placed at the top of the function
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt  #Must occur after setting backend
    return args
```

Otherwise you can pass the included library reference through a function return, in the same way you handle any other variable:

```
def main():
    plt, args = handleCommandLine()   # CHANGED HERE
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1)
    # ...    

def handleCommandLine():
    p = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    p.add_argument('--backend', '-b', default=None, help='Specify plotting backend')
    args = p.parse_args()

    if args.backend != None:
        matplotlib.use(args.backend)  #Must occur before importing pyplot

    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt   #Must occur after setting backend, if desired
    return plt, args   # CHANGED HERE
```

Comment: Very cool. Though I think the global approaches suggested elsewhere are a bit closer to what I want.

Comment: Yeah, I also added a `global` example while others were also writing those.

Comment: Thanks for the nice complete answer. Would you be OK with me editing to swap the order of your suggestions? Also, any reason you put the global plt just before the import rather than at the top of the function? Seems stylistic, but I'm interested in improving my style. Thanks

Comment: The `global` can go anywhere; I put it right by the `import` to make it clearer that the `plt` you were about to define was in fact a global. This is a style choice; a lot of people prefer to have their globals up front. But if the function is too long, when you read it, you'll forget it's a global by the time you get to the definition.

Comment: Oh, yeah: go ahead and swap them around if you like.

Answer (score 2):

An `import` statement is much like an assignment -- it assigns to a local name, unless you explicitly declare as `global`.  The following imports `plt` into the global namespace:

```
def handleCommandLine():
    global plt
    ...
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't.

I'd solve this by either returning `plt` from `handleCommandLine` or moving the import to `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Put `global plt` at the beginning of `handleCommandLine()`.